# Grails Ajax render to a GSP

Tags: grails, gsp

I'm trying to use "render" to fill a div in my view with a gsp form. Below is the code in my Controller. When I trigger it in the view, it returns nothing (whitespace). But if I change the below code to use normal form elements ( , etc), it does indeed display them...  Any thoughts on how I can rectify this?

```
render("""
<g:form name="editCommentForm" action="saveComments"> 
<g:textArea name="comments" value="comment" /> 
<g:submitToRemote update="editComments" />
</g:form>""" )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either create a template and render that, or [use groovyPagesTemplateEngine](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.br/2010/05/grails-goodness-use-gsp-template-engine.html).